# Ideal way/architecture to deliver large data over Web Services

Tags: web-services, architecture

We are trying to design 6 web services, which will serve another client component. The client component requires data from the web service we are implementing.

Now, the problem is, there is not 1 Web Service we are implementing, there is one Web Service which the client component hits, this initiates a series (5 more) of Web Services which gather data from their respective data stores and finally provide the data back to the original Web Service, which then delivers the data back to the client component.

So, if the requested data becomes *huge*, then, this will be a serious problem for our internal communication channel.

So, what do you guys suggest? What can be done to avoid overloading of the communication channel between the internal Web Service and at the same time, also delivering the data to the client component.

**Update 1**

Using 5 WS, where, 1WS does not know about the others, except the next one is a business requirement. Actually, 5 companies "small services" are being integrated.

We use Java and Axis2

Comment: What webservice framework are you using?  If you are using ASP.NET, there is an option to use binary xml serialization which can dramatically improve the performance.  Also, if you can avoid SOAP / xml based webservices and instead use plain text json, that would also greatly reduce your payloads.  Lastly, web services are design to expose a public API to the outside world, seriously consider talking straight to the db with the "series (5 or more)" web services if they are strictly internal.

Comment: Can you cache the results (perhaps with a given expiration interval) of the 5 external web services you are pulling from?  That's been an extremely effective solution for me in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've had a similar problem. Apart from trying to avoid it (eg for internal communication go direct to db instead of web service) you can mitigate it by at least not performing the 5 or so tasks in series. Make new threads to collect them all in parallel and process them at the end to reduce latency (except where they might contend for the same resource and bottle neck).

But before I'd do anything load test it and see if it is even an issue and get some baseline stats so you can see what improvement each change makes. Also sometimes you might be better off tweaking network settings or the actual network rather than trying to optimise the code - but again test and see.

Answer (score 1):

Put all the data on a temporary compressed file and give back the ftp url of the file.

The client fetches the big data chunk uncompress it and reads it. (maybe some authentication mechanism for the ftp server)

Comment: well, data store of the individual web services can only be accessed by those WS only, they cannot be public, even for some other component.